# Is there a way to get access to a git repository which was public but now is private?

Tags: git, github, github-api

For public git repositories on https://github.com one can use the API with `curl` and `jq` to list relevant repositories along with some information:

```
curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories    \
    --data-urlencode 'q=XXX+size:>25'                 \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw+json"   \
    | jq '.items[] | {html_url, watchers_count, language, name}'
```

While this works nicely for public repositories, is there a way to search repositories which once were public but then have been deleted or switched to private - and access them at the status when they were public? I.e., I am wondering if there is nothing like http://web.archive.org/ for git repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such feature in GitHub's Web API − and I don't see why one such API could be directly provided by GitHub to give (metadata) access to *deleted or switched to private* repositories.

However, I believe you may be interested in the Software Heritage project:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Heritage
- https://archive.softwareheritage.org/
- A Web API also seems available:
  https://archive.softwareheritage.org/api/

Comment: Many thanks - exactly what I was after.